# ID created by Table Generator is not persisted to object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I created the following entity class where the primary key is calculated by a Table Generator.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Article implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "ARTICLE_TABLE_GEN", table = "sequences", pkColumnName = "seq_name", valueColumnName = "seq_count", pkColumnValue = "ART_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ARTICLE_TABLE_GEN")
    private long id;
```

In the debug log, I read that the generation worked.

> [DEBUG] Generated identifier: 200, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator

The entites are managed by a JpaRepository.

```
@Repository
public interface IArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long> {

    List<Article> findByShortTextLike(String shortText);
}
```

In Java code, I access this repository via a Service.

```
@Service
public class ArticleService implements IArticleService {

    @Autowired
    private IArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Article getArticleByID(long id) {
        return this.articleRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Article createArticle(String shortText, String longText,
            String packageUnit, double weight, String group, char abcClass) {

        if (getArticleByShortText(shortText).size() == 0) {
            Article article = new Article();
            article.setShortText(shortText);
            article.setDescription(longText);
            article.setPackageUnit(packageUnit);
            article.setWeight(weight);
            article.setMaterialGroup(group);
            article.setClassABC(abcClass);
            this.articleRepository.saveAndFlush(article);
            return article;
        } else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Article> getArticleByShortText(String short_text) {
        return this.articleRepository.findByShortTextLike(short_text);
    }
}
```

After the service-method "createArticle" called the repository to save and flush the new instance to the database, this is perfectly done. However, the generated ID is not written to the object the method returns.

I remember that this was done when I used the AUTO_INCREMENT specification on the database column. Why does this not happen in the new case?

Comment: Show us the code of the repository, and show us how you're calling this repository and returning the entity.

Comment: @JBNizet: This should be fine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Spring-data-JPA, but the javadoc of saveAndFlush() shows that it returns an entity. So it probably uses `EntityManager.merge()` internally. Try changing your code to

```
article = this.articleRepository.saveAndFlush(article);
return article;
```

Comment: OK, quite easy, although I read the javadoc, I somehow could not derive this piece of code. @JBNizet: Thanks for your help again.